# Does useClass field in angular2 test make any difference if equal class is provided?

Tags: javascript, angular, jasmine, karma-runner, angular-services

I'm writing a **angular2** unit test (Jasmine) and I know that I should mock services instead of providing real ones, so I do the following:

```
  { provide: TranslateService, useClass: TranslateService }
```

Is this the correct way of doing it if you don't have another class created just for testing purposes (built one or custom one)?

It doesn't make any sense to me, should I be doing it this way if I will be using the TranslateService class or should I do it in a different way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need to use a mock service, then there is no need to create and inject a mock service, but instead just inject the original service.

In this case you can also use the shorter form

```
 TranslateService
```

instead of

```
 { provide: TranslateService, useClass: TranslateService }
```

If a component, directive, pipe, or service used in your test depends on `TranslateService` it must be provided somehow.
You will get an error message for a missing provider if you didn't.

If you don't provide a service and you don't get an exception, then the service isn't used or it is optional (`constructor(@Optional this.translateService:TranslateService){}`).
In this case you might or might not get an exception depending on whether your code executed during the test tries to access the service.

Comment: But if I want to use a mock service then I suppose I should create a new TranslateMockService just for testing purposes?

Comment: Yes, and then you need to use the long form for the provider `{ provide: TranslateService, useClass: TranslateMockService }`

Comment: Then others would jump in ;-)